# Option for choosing the Stack Exchange sites to show on "realtime questions"

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

I'm thinking that adding options to choose from what sites the [realtime questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) would fetch would be useful (with the available choosing of meta sub-sites).

Comment: You mean the question [here on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/questions)? You can already create a filter by clicking on the "create a filter" link to the right.

Comment: I mean [here on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime). There is no such link.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know of the filters you can create via the "hot" tab also apply to real-time. Perhaps worth a try.

Comment: Never saw that page, it's probably pretty new. Good idea, can't see much value in the current way it's working where it show questions from all across the network besides being cool feature.

Comment: @Bart: This link links to the [Filtered questions](http://stackexchange.com/filters) page. Which seems to be not a real-time list of questions.

Comment: @m0nhawk Like I said, I don't know what the various locations are that the filter applies to. Even more so since I don't use them. So no definitive answer from me on that.

Comment: I have the Filtered Question List but it comes up with sites which I am not added to or have ever visited. Should I ask this as a separate question?