# How do I limit questions in Stack Exchange's realtime view to languages I understand (such as English)?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, languages, realtime-questions

There is a stream of [realtime questions on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime):

[image: Realtime questions tab]

This stream is showing questions from all sites in the network, as they're posted or updated.

I'd like to filter out questions that are written in a language I don't speak. Can such an option please be added?

Comment: "*I'd like to filter out questions that are written in a language I don't speak.*" - all questions here and on other sites are in English, unless they say otherwise, like [Stack Overflow en Espanol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Ollie Or of course all the natural language sites, e.g. on [german.se], but the OP isn’t a member on any of these sites (at least visibly).

Comment: @Ollie yes, I get that, but, I don't speak Spanish or Russian. Is there no setting to hide questions you can't comprehend without using google translate?

Comment: @BeigeTheColor First:  What site are you on?

Comment: stackexchange.com right on the front page.

Comment: BeigeTheColor, do you mean here: https://stackexchange.com/filters/  and [then do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlWDy.jpg)?

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158898/option-for-choosing-the-stack-exchange-sites-to-show-on-realtime-questions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter for realtime questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302926/filter-for-realtime-questions)

Answer (score 5):

The [Realtime tab](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) on the frontpage of the Stack Exchange top level domain does not have any filtering options build in.

It has the purpose of piquing the visitors interest by showing them a stream of new questions that are posted across the network. It is not meant to show you stuff you don't want to see, it is meant to show you stuff you didn't dream of. Even the spam that gets posted (which is why that stream is used for [a different purpose as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically)).

What the designers of the site hope you would do is visit the actual Q/A site, found [in the sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) and keep an eye on their front-page. That gives you narrow scoped questions and answers on a topic you're interested in, where some sites offer Q/A in languages other then English.

If you still want to watch the realtime tab but not want to see questions from certain sites you would have to rely on userscripts. I know a couple exist but none I could find that have an actual post I could link you to.

Alternatively you could set-up a [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) as user [Rob pointed out in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354376/how-do-i-limit-questions-in-stackexchanges-realtime-view-to-languages-i-underst#comment1184244_354376)

Comment: Here is a user-script that I thought would be helpful: https://github.com/honnza/se-spam-helper

Comment: Thanks for the help, its unfortunate there aren't any built in filters.